# Moving Objects in Center-of-Mass Viewport

Tags: language-agnostic, graphics, viewport

I'm modeling a force-based physics simulation where several particles are interacting with each other.  The particles can move in such a way that a static viewport can easily lose track of them (imagine the whole group of particles moving off the screen to the right and the viewport displaying a blank background).

My current solution is to simply track the "center" of the particles by finding the min/max of the x's and y's and make the viewport's middle follow that.  It works fine (no need to find the true center of mass).  Here's a visual:

[image: Viewport]

My problem is I'm attempting to add the ability to manually drag particles around with the mouse.  I haven't found an elegant way to do this.  The problem is the translation between viewport coordinates and simulation coordinates is constantly changing because the viewport follows the particles' center.

When I mouse down on a particle I want it to have a fixed location in the simulation (it ignores all forces on it).  When I move the mouse with the button depressed I want the particle to move in the simulation.  I have achieved this.  However, it produces unpleasant side-effects because of the viewport and the other particles that are still in motion.  The particle isn't moving in the simulation when the mouse is depressed and stationary but it is moving on screen because the center of all the particles changes and the viewport adjusts accordingly.  The cursor is stationary so the particle "moves" out from under it.  When the mouse is moved ever-so-slightly, the particle teleports back under the cursor because the cursor's new position represents radically different simulation coordinates.

**Any suggestions for a nice, coherent user experience without the above side effects?**

---

I've already thought of:

- Pausing the simulation while the mouse is down
- Suspending viewport changes while the mouse is down
- Moving the mouse cursor as the viewport changes (really bad)

But they all have other bad side-effects or take away value from the simulation.

Also, I think this question is language and platform agnostic so don't attach literal and implementation-specific meanings to "viewport", "viewport coordinates", or "simulation coordinates".  Treat them as generic graphics concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the algorithm that adjusts the viewport to use the cursor's position as the origin of the transformation. That way the viewport and simulation coordinates at the cursor would remain fixed. You could just do this when the mouse is pressed, but it may also have pleasing results if it were done at all times.

It complicates the maths somewhat, but it doesn't seem like you're left with too many options.

Comment: This is very intriguing, I never thought of that.  There would be a quick jump on mouse down but it would be pleasing while dragging the particle around.  I'll get back to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a need to pause the simulation. As you are describing it, it seems that your mouse input (view input) directly changes the model data and the view is updated accordingly when next update/flush/whatever is issued.

Perhaps you could insert a new single particle that's only used during "animation", and that's not coupled to any of the other particles. While introducing this particle, you could hide the real particle (and it's edges). So while moving the mouse you are only updating the data of this animated particle. When the animation ends (you let the mouse go), the animated object is deleted, the real particle is updated with its data and shown again.

In one way this is a form of pause, since you are cheating the updating system. The data of the particle system is not updated during animation, it just looks like you are moving the particle of the real system, when you're in fact just cheating the user graphically. Hope this makes some sense, 2 am here :)

Comment: This would be an option except as it stands now, the selected particle does affect OTHER particles, it just doesn't get affected itself by them.  I do need to keep the particle "in" the simulation. So unfortunately I can't play graphics tricks